# Finding the perpendicular vector to a vector (in a plane)

Tags: vectors

I have a vector <-4,-4>. I want to find the perpendicular vector to this vector in a plane.

If a vector is perpendicular to another the dot product is zero.

Vector 1 = <.a,b>

Vector 2 = <.c,d>

Vector 1*Vector2 = 0 = a*c+b*d = 0

Plugging in my one vector I get this equation:

(-4)*c+(-4)*d = 0

I can see that if I add in the vectors <-1,1> and <1,-1> I fullfill the equation. What if I get much harder numbers? I dont feel like this is a very mathematical way to solve this problem.

Is there a more "correct" way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that (in your case), $c$ is determined by $d$ and the other way round, we have 
$$ -4c - 4d = 0 \iff 4c = -4d \iff d = -c $$
so for every $c \in \mathbf R$, the vector $(c,d) = (c,-c)$ is orthogonal to $(-4,4)$ and this are the only solutions. If you are given a general vector $(a,b)$, you can do the same:
$$ ac + bd = 0 \iff ac = -bd \iff d = -\frac{a}b \cdot c $$
this works as long as $b \ne 0$, the solutions are $(c, -\frac ab c)$ for any $c$ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any vector $\langle a,b\rangle$, one has $$\langle a,b\rangle\cdot \langle -b,a\rangle = -ab+ba = 0$$ so $\langle a,b\rangle$ and $\langle -b,a\rangle$ are perpendicular.

**Addendum:** The vector obtained by rotating $\langle a,b\rangle$ through an angle $\theta$ counterclockwise about the origin is
$$\langle a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta,a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta \rangle$$
Taking $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives $\langle -b,a\rangle$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have this done. You know $\langle a, b \rangle \cdot \langle -4, -4 \rangle = 0$. Then $-4a - 4 b = 0 \Rightarrow -4(a+b)=0 \Rightarrow a+b = 0 \Rightarrow a = -b$. Thus we are looking for all vectors of the form $a \langle 1, -1 \rangle$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. For instance if we take $a = 1.3$, then $\langle 1.3, -1.3 \rangle$ is orthogonal to $\langle -4, -4 \rangle$.